# Subset Sum - 2D Dynamic Programming

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm trying to find **ALL** the subsets of a set of n numbers that has a sum of m. For example if I had the set `(10,20,30,40,40,50,80)` and `m = 90` the subsets are `(10,80)`, `(20,30,40)` and `(40,50)`. I have code that will find small cases like this using something like...

```
M[i, j] = max(M[i − 1, j], M[i − 1, j − A[i])
```

then backtracking using...

```
if (M[n][m]!=0)
{
    for ( i = n; i >= 1; i --)
        if (M[i - 1][j]!=M[i][j])
        {
            printf ("Use item %d = %d\n", i, A[i]);
            j -= A[i];
        }
}
```

but when I try larger test cases it will not return all the subsets. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: How are we supposed to help you if you don't show us the code you are using? Please don't show all your code from your project, just the relevant bits.

Comment: First: are the numbers all positive (or at least nonnegative)? Second, your example contains 40 twice, is that a typo or are multiple elements allowed?

Comment: all elements are positive and multiple elements are allowed.

Answer (score 1):

All numbers being positive allows pruning, which greatly reduces the complexity (I don't know how much on average, though). For large sets, you'll probably need a more refined algorithm, but here goes:

1. sort the (multi)set into an array, say `nums`; for the example, nums = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 40, 50, 80 }
2. create an array of cumulative sums, `cum`; that would be cum = { 10, 30, 60, 100, 140, 190, 270 }

Now (C-ish pseudocode)

```
void parts(target, index, set){  // assuming we only want to print the sets out
    if (target == 0){
        print out set;
        return;
    }
    while(index >= 0 && nums[index] > target) --index; // skip too large numbers
    if (index < 0 || cum[index] < target) return;  // done, all numbers too large or total too small
    for(; index >= 0 && cum[index] >= target; --index){  // we can stop when the total sum is too small
        add nums[index] to set;
        parts(target - nums[index], index-1, set);
        remove nums[index] from set;
        // if no duplicate sets are desired, skip duplicates, for the example,
        // (40,50) would be created twice without skipping:
        // while(index > 0 && nums[index-1] == nums[index]) --index;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* first we sort M with a quicksort, for instance, 
   whose an efficient implementation can be easily found on the web. */
M = quicksort(M);

/* we don't consider elements greater than m 
   so we compute the index of the greatest element to consider */
int max = n - 1;
for (; max > 0 && M[max] > m; max--);

int total = 1 << (max + 1);
for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)
{
    /* In this loop we'll go through all the possible subsets of M */
    int sum = 0;
    for (int k=0; k<n; k++)
    {
        if ((1 << k) & i)
        {
             s += M[k]; 

             /* if s is greater than m no need to go further */
             if (s > m)
             {
                 break;
             }
        }
    }
    if (sum == m)
    {
        /* Here we have found a successful subset so 
           we can output it however we want.
           It is composed of all the elements used 
           to build s in the loop above */        
    }
}
```

Comment: If we are looping through all of the possible subsets then it would not be dynamic programming, correct?

Comment: you can write a solution that is more dynamic: for each element of you set you have two optionw: it is in a successful subset or not. Around this idea you can build a method called recursively for each new element to consider but at the end it will still go through the 2^n possible subsets as you want ALL the subsets whose sum equals m

Comment: @PierrOz it would normally not go through all, since you can prune (if the elements are nonnegative). In the example, you wouldn't need to consider any subsets containing 80 and 50 (pruning 2^(n-2) subsets) etc.

Comment: Oh god, `pow(2, n)`? Why do people do that?

Comment: @DanielFischer I don't understand why we shuoldn't consider 80 and 50 in the example? The subsets {10,80} and {50,40} match the condition.

Comment: @PierrOz I meant: no subset containing both, 80 _and_ 50.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance I'm only a student but is the above solution dynamic programing? If so what is the general case and where is the backtrack?

Comment: `';'` after `for (; max > 0 && M[max] > m; max--)`?